# Storage Procedures vs Singleton Java

Tags: java, sql, performance, stored-procedures, singleton

Currently I made a connection to a database in this way:

**MyClass.java**

```
try {
    DataSource datasource = JNDILoader.getDataSourceObject(pathToSource);
    Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
    connection = datasource.getConnection();
    stmt = connection.prepareStatement("{call storageProcedureXXX(?,?)}");
    stmt.setString(1, "X");
    stmt.setString(2, "Y");            
    result = stmt.executeQuery();
}catch (SQLException){
    //TODO
}catch(Exception){
    //TODO
}
```

That works for 1 class that makes the requests for the data, but , would be better if I create a singleton class and get the connection from it? (performance?, maintenability?, simplicity?). Which option would be better: Singleton vs StorageProcedures per each request?.

Note: At the end, the application (Restful Web Service) will need to connect to different databases to load data for different specialized classes,  even ,  the classes would need loads data from plain text.

Comment: what's the context? is this in a webapp? a script?

Comment: I'm really confused, you are mixing stored procedures and singleton, two completely different things on completely different abstraction level (way of encapsulating business logic and design pattern).

Comment: I'm developping a Restful Web Service, so, the code above is part of a Class that connects to the database, but, because i will need many classes querying many data sources (plaintext, DB, propertiesFiles, etc), I want to be sure of the best approach, thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you are mixing two different things: singleton and stored procedures. [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) is design pattern, and [stored procedures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stored_procedure) are procedures executed on database, typically encapsulating some business logic.

What you wrote is not really preferred way of connecting to database. If you have many request and create one connection for each request son you will have problems with too many connections to database. You should use [connection pool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_pool). The most famous for Java is [DBCP](http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/). Another one is [c3p0](http://sourceforge.net/projects/c3p0/).

For connection on different databases you should use something like [Hibernate](http://www.hibernate.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Stored procedure are executed on the database. You pass/retrieve data to/from it through the connection.

You have to check if it is thread safe (I don't think so), if you'll do concurrent calls or not.

Generally a stored procedure = 1 transaction happening in the database.

Why are you using stored procedure in the 1st place?